# Laravel html_entity_decode using UTF-8

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8, html-entities, html-encode

I am using Laravel 4, with PHP and MySQL.
Everything is in UTF-8

I have blog titles stored in my database, that look like :

`This is an "example" post title`

Now on my website, I have images using `alt` `title` attributes.
When I `echo` my blog title, I get something like:

`<img src="image.jpg" alt="This is an "example" post title" />`

Which of course is terrible.

I have tried the following:

`{{ html_entity_decode($blog_title, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') }}`

But it doesn't seem to do anything. What am I missing?

I would like the title to display like this: `This is an &quot;example&quot; post title`

Comment: Is there a html_entity_encode?

Comment: Not that I know of. I tried it but returns an error.

Comment: There is `htmlentities()` but it doesn't change the quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [triple curly quotes](http://laravel.com/docs/templates):

```
{{{ $blog_title }}}
```

The [html_entity_decode()](http://php.net/html_entity_decode) does the opposite (and hence leaves `"` untouched). As a memory hook:

```
" -> encoding -> &quot;
&quot; -> decoding -> "
```

Comment: `<img src="image.jpg" alt="{{{ $post->title }}}" />` still returns `<img src="image.jpg" alt="This is an "example" post title" />`

Comment: You are sure these are ASCII quotes and not ["curly" ones](http://codepoints.net/U+201C) (which would be okay)?

Comment: I was doing `{{ e($post->title) }}` but it seems that `{{{ $post->title }}}` resolved the problem, thanks!

Comment: Yes, that would explain it. `e()` does echoing directly, while `{{ }}` acts on the value of the variable. Hence: value of `e($foo)` is the empty string, `{{{ "" }}}` does nothing, and `e()` did not escape anything.

Comment: Triple curly quote is not working for me in laravel 5.7.  My code is <p>{{{ $postedArticleData->pa_full_desc }}}</p>

Answer (score 4):

I am using 5.7 laravel version. Below solution solved my problem:

```
<p>{!! $pa_full_desc !!}</p>
```

here $pa_full_desc has dummy html content eg.

```
<p>In lobortis pharetra mattis. Morbi nec nibh iaculis, <a href="#">bibendum augue a</a>, ultrices nulla. Nunc velit ante, lacinia id tincidunt eget, faucibus nec nisl.</p>
```

This worked for me. Thanks for asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
{!! html_entity_decode($str) !!}
```

This is how we use it.